# Parameter can be IEnumerable - How to change code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

resharper says **Parameter can be IEnumerable**, for the parameter "gameObjects". How do I change the code to this, and what's the benefit of doing so?

```
Transform GetClosestObject (Transform[] gameObjects) {
    Transform bestTarget = null;
    float closestDistanceSqr = Mathf.Infinity;
    Vector3 currentPosition = transform.position;
    foreach(Transform potentialTarget in gameObjects) {
        Vector3 directionToTarget = potentialTarget.position - currentPosition;
        float dSqrToTarget = directionToTarget.sqrMagnitude;
        if(dSqrToTarget < closestDistanceSqr) {
            closestDistanceSqr = dSqrToTarget;
            bestTarget = potentialTarget;
        }
    }

    return bestTarget;
}
```

Comment: `Transform GetClosestObject (IEnumerable<Transform> gameObjects)` - try this.

Comment: I tried that before but got `'IEnumerable' is not a known identifier`

Comment: I don't see any problem with your current code. I think you should explain what the problem is. Post the code that's not working and explain what you expect it to do.

Comment: @Niclas are you using `omnisharp`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using omnisharp in sublime/unity. The code is working, I'm just trying to get rid of warnings. I can disable specific warnings in the settings, but I also try to learn C# and learn how to make the code better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resharper is telling you that you can change the gameObjects parameter to be of type IEnumerable rather than array. This results in a more flexible method signature as it allows the caller to input an array or List or other IEnumerable implementation.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ParameterTypeCanBeEnumerable.Global.html

IEnumerable is found under the System.Collections.Generic namespace. To use, add

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

to the top of your file.

To fix your code, change

```
Transform GetClosestObject (Transform[] gameObjects) {
```

to

```
Transform GetClosestObject (IEnumerable<Transform> gameObjects) {
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a better explanation, since I wanted to understand the point of it, but the first line code from A.Hamzavi below should perhaps be added, so this would be the best answer.

Comment: If you use List<Transform> gameObjects, as suggested by A.Hamzavi,  the same warning will be shown. I've updated my answer to show the correct code to use.

Comment: Thank you. Using List<Transform> actually didn't show the warning anymore, but does this mean I can feed either a List or an Array of Transforms as parameters this method?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - you can pass an array of Transforms or List of Transforms or other collection (of Transforms) which implements IEnumerable. I'm surprised that it didn't show the warning for  List<Transform> as using a list here is virtually no different to using an array with respect to making the method more agnostic as the warning suggests.

Comment: IEnumerable would be the way to go anyway. you should program to the interface - not the implementation, and only allow access to what is needed. In the method all it is using the parameter for is to enumerate through the items, so ienumerable would allow any type that implements ienumerable to be passed in without changing what the code already does. if you needed to add items to that parameter or access elements in it using indexing, then you wouldnt want ienumerable, but maybe IList<T> instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Hmm, now even though I use `Transform GetClosestObject (IEnumerable<Transform> gameObjects) {` it still says **Parameter can be IEnumerable**. Not sure if this is a bug in omnisharp since I still get it even with List, which didn't show it before..