# Parameter can be declared with base type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Resharper says **Parameter can be declared with base type** for this code, how do I fix that, and what's the benefit? I'm very new to C# so sorry if I missed some basic concept..

```
IEnumerator RemoveGameObject(float waitTime, GameObject go) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    Destroy(go);
}
```

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357727/resharper-suggests-parameter-can-be-of-type-basetype), but didn't understand it.. maybe I need to read up on base types..

Comment: The truth is, you don't win anything "declaring it with base type", so just ignore it. I wouldn't use resharper anyways :p

Comment: duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357727/resharper-suggests-parameter-can-be-of-type-basetype

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll set that warning to ignore. I think for the most part resharper helps me clean my code, to remind me to use switch statements and ternary if statements, and unused parameters.

Comment: _"How do I fix that"_ There's nothing to "fix", but you can follow the suggestion by using the base type. Doesn't Resharper provide you an option to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a suggestion based on best practices, design guidelines and programming principles.

When creating and deciding on parameter types for methods, you should use a parameter type that meets the minimum requirements the method needs to perform its job. You would use the Interface which meets those requirements, or the lowest class in the inheritance chain which meets those requirements.

In your example the method "***Destroy(p)***" seems to only use properties or methods which not only exist in the ***GameObject***, but also in its base type (the class it inherits from). "***Destroy(p)***" does not need the "extra stuff" that ***GameObject*** brings with it. So by using the base of ***GameObject***, which meets the minimum requirements of what "***Destroy(p)***" needs to perform its duties, you allow any class derived from that base to also gain the ability to be passed in as a parameter to "***Destroy(p)***".

An example:
Consider this code (probably not the best, but should do)

```
public class Animal
{
    public void Eat(Food food) { }
    public void Breath() { }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public void Bark() { }
}

public class Human : Animal
{
    public void Speak() { }
}
```

now i create a method like so:

```
 public void PerformLifeDuties(Human joe, Food food)
{
    joe.Eat(food);
    joe.Breath();
}
```

i just limited my code. Now i cannot pass in an ***Animal***, a ***Dog*** or any derived type of ***Animal***, I can only pass in a ***Human***. Even though the only requirements for that method are for it to be an ***Animal***, so I can call ***eat*** and ***breath***. The better way would have been to make the parameter ***Animal***.

```
 public void PerformLifeDuties(Animal animal, Food food)
{
    animal.Eat(food);
    animal.Breath();
}
```

now i can use this method with ***Human***, ***Dog*** and derived types. If my method needed to make the ***Animal*** speak, then i would've needed to specify at least ***Human***.

From Microsoft's page:

> ✓ DO use the least derived parameter type that provides the
>   functionality required by the member.

You can check out some of Microsoft's C# design guidelines here: [Parameter Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/parameter-design)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check this out as soon as possible and accept your answer.

Comment: i just noticed you were the same author of https://stackoverflow.com/q/48374841/6368401 . the reasoning is the same as what @sparkplug was suggesting - contrary to what Hamzavi had suggested. program to the interface, or lowest class. general rule of thumb.

Comment: Great, it took a couple of reads but it makes sense. When making a game for the first time, it’s more do first, think later which creates problems like this.. :) the examples were perfect!

Comment: glad it helped. a second go around is part of design. even a third or fourth wouldnt hurt.